# Spotipy Current Track Data - Getting current track ID

Tags: python, json, spotify, spotipy

I don't see a whole lot of info on `current_user_playing_track()` for Spotipy so hoping someone will be able to help me on this.

```php
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import json
import requests

cid = 'my client id'
secret = 'my client secrets'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:7777/callback'
username = 'my username'
scope = 'user-read-currently-playing'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, cid, secret, redirect_uri)
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(token)

def get_current_song():
    # Get track information
    track = spotify.current_user_playing_track()
    print(json.dumps(track, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
    artist = json.dumps(track['item']['album']['artists'][0]['name'])
    track = json.dumps(track['item']['name'])

    return artist, track

def main():
    artist, track = get_current_song()
    if artist !="":
        print("Currently playing " + artist + " - " + track + "--TRACK ID--")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works with no trouble, but I want the track ID so I can make another function to analyze the audio but when I add this

```php
def get_current_song():
    # Get track information
    track = spotify.current_user_playing_track()
    print(json.dumps(track, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
    artist = json.dumps(track['item']['album']['artists'][0]['name'])
    track = json.dumps(track['item']['name'])
    track_id = json.dumps(track['item']['id'])
    return artist, track
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Projects\spotipy\kasify.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Projects\spotipy\kasify.py", line 27, in main
    artist, track = get_current_song()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Projects\spotipy\kasify.py", line 23, in get_current_song
    track_id = json.dumps(track['item']['id'])
                          ~~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code and I deleted unnecessary stuff.

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from pprint import pprint

cid = 'my client id'
secret = 'my client secrets'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:7777/callback'
scope = 'user-read-currently-playing'

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=cid,
                                               client_secret=secret,
                                               redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                                               scope=scope))

def get_current_song():
    # Get track information
    track = spotify.current_user_playing_track()
    pprint(track)
    artist = track["item"]["artists"][0]["name"]
    t_name = track["item"]["name"]
    t_id = track["item"]["id"]
    return artist, t_name, t_id

def main():
    artist, track, tid = get_current_song()
    if artist !="":
        print(f"Currently playing {artist} - {track} - {tid}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, that does look a lot nicer but I'm still trying to figure how to the track ID

```code
track = track["item"]["name"]
```
This gets a valid track name with no errors

```code
track_id = track["item"]["id"]
```
When I add this I get an error like in my post and I'm confused why because ID is listed under ITEM.

Comment: @error500 I've now added track id (tid) to the code. Note: the code still gives an error when nothing is playing.

Comment: I'm getting the same error
```code
tid = track["item"]["id"]
          ~~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

Comment: @error500 in my (old) code and your code, the variable *track* with track data gets overridden with the track name. So, I've now changed the second variable, so now it should be fixed. (sorry for not testing first.)

Comment: thank you, also now I know why it wasn't working